# Как вернуть промежуточное значение?

Tags: golang

Как вернуть status = 2, не прерывая цикл [и функцию]?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// Значения status: 1 - "успешно"; 2 - "неудачно впервые"; 3 = "неудачны все попытки".
func SendMail() (status int) {
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ { // максимальное количество попыток.
        isSuccess := rand.Intn(2) == 1 // случайное число true/false для теста

        if isSuccess {
            fmt.Println("Успешно! i =", i)
            return 1
        }

        if !isSuccess && i == 1 {
            fmt.Println("Неуспешно впервые. i =", i)
            status = 2
        }
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }

    status = 3
    fmt.Println("Неудачны все попытки. i = 5")
    return
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    var my_status = SendMail()
    if my_status == 1 {
        fmt.Println("main: Успешно!")
    }
    if my_status == 2 {
        fmt.Println("main: Неуспешно впервые.")
    }
    if my_status == 3 {
        fmt.Println("main: Неудачны все попытки.")
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/X44qX3w4VYm

Comment: Пишите промежуточные значения в `channel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказали — пишите в канал. Вот работающий переделанный ваш пример
https://go.dev/play/p/-olSoQuWLuV

P.S: Ну и число попыток снаружи можно передать

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type SendAttempt struct {
    status int
    first  bool
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    attempts := make(chan SendAttempt)

    go SendMail(attempts)

    for {
        select {
        case atm, ok := <-attempts:
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("Исчерпаны все попытки")
                return
            }

            if atm.status == 1 {
                fmt.Println("Успешно!")
                return
            }

            if atm.status == 2 {
                msg := ""
                msg = msg + "Неуспешно"
                if atm.first {
                    msg = msg + " впервые"
                }

                fmt.Println(msg)
                continue
            }

            if atm.status == 3 {
                fmt.Println("main: Неудачны все попытки.")
                continue
            }
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
}

// Значения status: 1 - "успешно"; 2 - "неудачно впервые"; 3 = "неудачны все попытки".
func SendMail(attempts chan<- SendAttempt) {
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        isSuccess := rand.Intn(2) == 1 

        if isSuccess {
            attempts <- SendAttempt{1, false}
            continue
        }

        if !isSuccess {
            attempts <- SendAttempt{2, i == 1}
            continue
        }

        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }

    attempts <- SendAttempt{3, false}
    close(attempts)
}
```